# How would I increment the number upon double clicking image?

Tags: javascript, debugging

As of now, I can successfully upload an image and display it in the browser and display that it has 0 likes initially.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the user double clicks on the image, the `0 likes` should become `1 likes` (I know it's not grammatically correct, I just want it to function properly first before moving onto that issue).

If you look at the console logs, it indeed shows the like number switching back and forth with every double click, which's good.  The bad part is I'm not sure how to display that change in the browser.

I've tried so many different ways but running out of options.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

JS file:

```
function previewImages() {
  var preview = document.createElement('div');
  preview.className = "preview";
  document.body.appendChild(preview);

if (this.files) {
    [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
}

function readAndPreview(file) {
    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
        return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
    } // else...

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;

        var initialCountOfLikes = 0;
        var zeroLikes = document.createElement('p');
        var zeroLikesTextNode = document.createTextNode(initialCountOfLikes + " likes");
        document.body.appendChild(zeroLikes.appendChild(zeroLikesTextNode));

        preview.appendChild(image);

        image.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.detail === 2 && initialCountOfLikes === 0) {
                console.log("clicked twice");
                initialCountOfLikes++;
                console.log("initialCountOfLikes++ => " + initialCountOfLikes);
            }

            else if(event.detail === 2 && initialCountOfLikes === 1) {
                console.log("inside second if block");
                initialCountOfLikes--;
                console.log("initialCountOfLikes-- => " + initialCountOfLikes);
            }

            document.body.appendChild(zeroLikes.appendChild(zeroLikesTextNode));

        };


    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}

  document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages);
```

Here's my HTML:

```
 <div id="file-input-wrapper">
    <input type="file" id="file-input" name="files" style="display: none;"/>
    <label for="file-input" id="LblBrowse">
        Upload your photo!
    </label>
</div>
```

console logs:

```
clicked twice
index.js:126 initialCountOfLikes++ => 1
index.js:130 inside second if block
index.js:132 initialCountOfLikes-- => 0
index.js:124 clicked twice
index.js:126 initialCountOfLikes++ => 1
index.js:130 inside second if block
index.js:132 initialCountOfLikes-- => 0
```

Comment: It may be helpful to look at changing the `innerText` property of the `zeroLikes` element. (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Your event.detail is registering as one, so I changed your listener to a dblClick event and removed that from the if statement. And nodes use nodeValue instead of innerText, so corrected in solution.

```
        window.onload = function(){
    function previewImages() {
      var preview = document.createElement('div');
      preview.className = "preview";
      document.body.appendChild(preview);

    if (this.files) {
        [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
    }

    function readAndPreview(file) {
        // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
        if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
            return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
        } // else...

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var image = new Image();
            image.height = 100;
            image.title = file.name;
            image.src = this.result;

            var initialCountOfLikes = 0;
            var zeroLikes = document.createElement('p');
            var zeroLikesTextNode = document.createTextNode(initialCountOfLikes + " likes");
            document.body.appendChild(zeroLikes.appendChild(zeroLikesTextNode));

            preview.appendChild(image);

            image.ondblclick = function (event) {
                if (initialCountOfLikes === 0) {
                    console.log("clicked twice");
                    initialCountOfLikes++;
                    console.log("initialCountOfLikes++ => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                }

                else if(initialCountOfLikes === 1) {
                    console.log("inside second if block");
                    initialCountOfLikes--;

                    console.log("initialCountOfLikes-- => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                }

 zeroLikesTextNode.nodeValue = initialCountOfLikes + " likes";
           document.body.appendChild(zeroLikes.appendChild(zeroLikesTextNode));

            };


        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    }

      document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages);
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding `zeroLikesTextNode.innerText = initialCountOfLikes + " likes";` above `initialCountOfLikes++;` and `initialCountOfLikes--;` but still getting the same output in console as above and no increment/decrement in the browser.

Comment: You need to add it after you have performed the increment/decrement. Otherwise your counter is still at the initial value of 0. Try placing it underneath where the count change occurs

Comment: Yeah I meant to say I tried it above and after, forgot to include the after part in my post.  Still got the same result :(

Comment: Hmm. Can you post the HTML with this too so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Just posted my HTML file in my original post

Comment: I just updated the answer. Since you are looking for an event detail of 2 (double click) in the if and else if statements, just change the event to a dblclick event, and remove the event.detail piece from the if statements. Also, I overlooked the part about it being a node, so instead on innerText use nodeValue.

Comment: Thank you. If you can mark this as the correct answer it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can start a timer, and measure the time between clicks, when the image is clicked. If the time between clicks is less than some number, then you can increase your count.

Something like the following:

```
firstClick = true;
let timer = new Date().getMilliseconds();
let someValue; // set this

image.onclick = function (event) {
    let currentTime = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    if(firstClick){
        timer = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    }
    let difference = currentTime - timer;
    if(difference >= someValue && !firstClick){
        return;
    }

    firstClick = !firstClick;
    timer = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    if (event.detail === 2 && initialCountOfLikes === 0 && !firstClick) {
        console.log("clicked twice");
        initialCountOfLikes++;
        console.log("initialCountOfLikes++ => " + initialCountOfLikes);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to what I'm doing below where you use a module to increment a private counter. The comments should be enough to explain what exactly is going on in the code:

```js
//Load the existing number of likes from the server (im just using 5 as example)
const initialLikes = 5;

//Initialize a "like" counter
const likes = ((quantity) => {
  //This is the count
  let i = quantity;

  //We return a module that allows us to increment the count or get the current count
  return {
    increment: () => i += 1,
    quantity: () => i
  }
})(initialLikes || 0);

//Store DOM elements we're accessing in variables
const captionEl = document.querySelector('#countEl');
const imgEl = document.querySelector('#puppyImg');

//Our double click handler:
const onDblClick = e => {
  //Increment the count via our module, then update the count text
  likes.increment();
  captionEl.textContent = likes.quantity();
}

const init = () => {
  //Set the initial count text on screen
  captionEl.textContent = likes.quantity();

  //Attach the event handler to the img
  imgEl.addEventListener('dblclick', onDblClick);
};

init();
```

```css
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img id="puppyImg" src="https://s.abcnews.com/images/Lifestyle/puppy-ht-3-er-170907_4x3_992.jpg" height="160" width="190" alt="Cute puppy photo" />
<br /> Likes: <span id="countEl"></span>
```